# Unable to expose a public page referenced in an email to let users reset their password in a Vue JS, Node JS and Mongo db website structure

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, single-page-application, reset-password

I'm working on a Vue JS, Node and Mongodb website with user management features. I implemented a "Reset Password" functionality: a user can access his profile page, press the reset password button and this will trigger a node functionaly, which is gonna send him an email containing a URL link pointing to a Vue JS component exposed to the public called "ResetPassword".

The URL has this format: /ResetPassword/<token_assiged_to_user>
(for ex. /ResetPassword/5fa3ff9e87e0fdba7097e3bfb5e02e450ca1e1cf )

I tested the functionality locally and it works like a charm, the problem is than since I move the implementation to an actual testing server the ResetPassword page doesn't work anymore.

I marked as "public" the component in the index.js router file like this:

```
{
      path: '/ResetPassword/:token',
      name: 'ResetPassword',
      component: ResetPassword,
      meta: {
        public: true    
      }
}
```

plus I'm using Vue-Router in my component to allow it to be exposed (here's just the beginning of the component):

```
<script>
  import axios from "axios";
  import Vue from 'vue'
  import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

  Vue.use(VueRouter)
  export default {
    name: 'ResetPassword',
    props: {
      token: String
    },
[...]
```

The ResetPassword page doesn't even seem to be rendered while clicking the link and it appears entirely blank on the screen. The error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'" is displayed referred to the manifest file and here's the error that pops-up when I look at the console in the browser:
[console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmOB7.png)

The routing configuration is set to "historymode" at the moment and I also implemented a fallback method to redirect towards our homepage.

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening? Am I missing something? I know Vue JS allows to only create some kind of "Single Page Applications", but I thought exposing a public component like I described could be feasible.

Thanks so much to everyone in advance.

UPDATE:
Here follows the main.js file requested in the comments below:

```
import App from './App'
import BackToTop from './components/BackToTopComponent'
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'
import Cookies from 'vue-cookies'
import router from './router'
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueMoment from 'vue-moment'
import VueSession from 'vue-session'


import 'bootstrap';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'

const moment = require('moment')
require('moment/locale/it')



Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
Vue.use(Cookies)
Vue.use(VueSession)
Vue.use(VueMoment, { moment })
Vue.filter('siNo', value => (value ? 'Si' : 'No'))


Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.component('BackToTop', BackToTop)

Vue.prototype.$eventBus = new Vue()
Vue.prototype.$baseUrl = '{baseUrl}';

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    components: { App, BackToTop },
    template: '<App/>'
})
```

Comment: It seems like the script is breaking at the beginning "<" where you have the "<script>" tag. did you upload the same code to as in the local or did you minify the js when you upload to the server?

Comment: I updated the code as it is, without any kind of minification. The code is ok, the <script> tag is written properly and there are no syntax errors. Also, analyzing the "sources" tab in the developer tools view in chrome the website structure seems reduced and only contains the above mentioned component, which is weird.

Comment: *uploaded (of course)

Comment: do you use webpack to compile?

Comment: Yeah, I do use it

Comment: if you can add the main JS file related to this page which you are provide to the webpack to compile. it would be better to debug more into this

Comment: Thanks @ChathurangaK. I just updated the post and added the main.js file you mentioned. Hope this can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same issue in my project!

[Unable to acess links (copying and pasting) whitin my Site : Node.js - Express.js - Webpack - Vue.js - historymode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64087800/unable-to-acess-links-copying-and-pasting-whitin-my-site-node-js-express-j)

The problem was related to my weback.prod.conf.js file.

Try to add this info to your "output" attribue in your webpack conf file :
publicPath: '/'

you should have something like this :

```
output: {
    publicPath: '/'
}
```